# Best way to clone SSD to larger SSD with Ubuntu

Tags: ssd, dd, clone, clonezilla

I have Ubuntu as OS on 256GB SSD and have bought a larger 1TB SSD.

Is Clonezilla a good option to clone SSD?
Will Clonezilla use same size on new SSD and leave remaining GB’s as unallocated space?
Is this a good way to do it?
Have also been reading up a bit about “dd “, is this a good option for a novice user.
I have M2 SSD caddy for Cloning and new 1TB SSD is unformatted. All advice welcome

Haven’t tried anything yet, in research mode.

Comment: Problem is we only deal with problems not advice ;)  The best option to use is the one YOU are comfortable with. My method would be to install a new Ubuntu on the new ssd and then mount the old one and rsync or copy personal files.

Comment: DD not really recommended for new users. Its nickname is Data Destroyer. Any typo and you totally destroy data. I have only used it a very few times in 15 years. It will  leave new drive as same size as old drive. And then you have to resize, move & update gpt partition data. Lots of terminal commands required. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI boot mode & use gpt partitioning which will be default.

Comment: Well, went ahead with dd. As follows sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sdc status=progress. Everything went smoothly  swapped larger SDD over and booted straight to desktop, all files all app intact. I have 768 GB of free space which I will attempt to resize, move & update gpt partition data as advised in your post oldfred. Surly there is no easy way using “disks” to just extend out ? Thanks for all help  ill update once next step completed